# Get resource xml remotely

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to figure out how to get a resource xml from a remote location. Ideally download it from a online server and save it to a protected area on the users phone and be able to call the xml inside the app. The xml would include your standard string arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar requirement in my app. I had to download a xml that contained urls some urls like Terms and conditions, help, etc. You can make a request for the xml in your splash activity(if you have one), or you can initiate the request in the background as soon as the app is started, and then whenever you get the result, you can parse the xml and store the details in your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's going to work because the xml resource needs to be available at compile so that AAPT can package it up in a way that allows you to reference those resources from your code.

Comment: Ok My app is an episode guide for a tv show. What method would you recommend to use then so i can add new episodes without recompiling and updating each time.